# How can I find the target_link_libraries name of a library (with :: namespace)

Tags: c++, cmake

### Project Environment

For a cpp project like the following, using multiple libraries: How do I find the libraries' names to pass into `find_package` and `target_link_libraries`? Is there any consistent standard or an easy way to find them?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

...

find_package(nlohmann_json 3.11.2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SQLite3 3.6.23.1 REQUIRED)
find_package(log4cxx 1.1.0.0 REQUIRED)
include(FindEXPAT) # required for log4cxx when built from source
find_package(PahoMqttCpp REQUIRED)

...

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    nlohmann_json::nlohmann_json
    SQLite::SQLite3
    log4cxx
    PahoMqttCpp::paho-mqttpp3
)
```

### My Question

I know that the double-colon `::` syntax means namespaced libraries, to force C++ to not look for .so files.

But how can I find these namespaced names? Neither the part before the `::`, nor the part after the `::` are consistent with the text in `find_package`, which itself is not consistent with the library package name that I am using to install the libraries from the ubuntu package archives.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to say: Read the documentation of the corresponding find_package script. For example, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindSQLite3.html or https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindEXPAT.html

Comment: `find_package` can also search for `XXXConfig.cmake` or `XXX-config.cmake`. If the package ships with that you can find the name of the target inside those.

Answer (score 2):

In general the various findXXX.cmake docs are reasonably OK. For example,

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindEXPAT.html tells you that on success, it has defined an `EXPAT::EXPAT` target for import.
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindSQLite3.html tells you that on success, it has defined an `SQLite::SQLite3` import target (note the absence of a '3' in the namespace)

If that fails, you can always dive into the installed findXXX.cmake scripts in the `share\cmake-3.26\Modules` folder and inspect the code itself.